# Как скомпилировать apk из py в Pydroid 3

Tags: python, android, apk

Я наткнулся на статью в интернете где говорится о том, что с помощью Pydroid3 на телефоне можно скомпилировать код на python в apk. Так ли это? И если да то как? Я мучаюсь уж третий день с компиляцией поможет хоть что, но Linux у меня нет. Если кто хочет помочь то пишите